# Javascript Regexp to search certain class

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple Regexp with the following code :

```
<img[^>]+src="([^">]+)"
```

This regexp allows me to get the src of each img of my document.
What I am trying to do without any success, is to add a class condition to it, something that will find all the src of my images which have a certain class.
I tried something like that :

```
<img[^>]+src="([^">]+)" *class="name_of_my_class"
```

but this only works if the class is inserted after the src, and i need the regexp to work in reverse sens to.

Thanks for any helps !

Comment: Are you only trying to get the `src` attribute from `img` tags of a certain `class`? Why do you need regex to do this?

Comment: You might be better off using an HTML parser instead - especially if you need to add or modify attributes. For example, I use Ruby and Nokogiri. Using RegEx is not the way to go.

Comment: My mistake, I forget to precise that I'm parsing a string and not directly the DOM (I parse an Ajax response, before injecting it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already been said that you shouldn't use regex blablabla...
Still, I can deal with my conscience if I make you learn something about regular expressions at the same time, so, let's do it. The key tool here is the [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
/<img(?=[^>]+class="name_of_my_class")[^>]+src="([^">]+)"/
```

The lookahead allows you check something ahead without moving the pointer inside your string. So basically, you check something ahead.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to traverse the document, searching for classes and returning attributes, you may find it is easier to use the DOM querying tools:

```
var imgSrcArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img.myClassName'),0)
                       .map(function(img) {
                          return img.getAttribute('src');
                       });
```

(example assumes a modern browser with querySelector and Array.prototype.map enabled)

Comment: Thank for your response @steveukx. The fact is that I'm parsing a string (an ajax response) and not directly the DOM. Can this work ?

Comment: Assuming that the string is valid HTML, you can create an element, set the content as the `innerHTML` and then query on that element: `var el = document.createElement('div'); el.innerHTML = myHtmlString;` then replace the `document` in the example above with `el`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering both situations might be a solution, class either before or after the src attribute:

```
<img[^>]+?((src="([^">]+)"[^>]*?class="name_of_my_class")|(class="name_of_my_class"[^>]*?src="([^">]+)"))[^>]*>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i dont really know how exactly do this in regexp but i think you can do it as followed :

```
<img 
    {any charakter except >}* 
    (
        {check for class} {any charakter except >}* {get src} 
        ||
        {get src} {any charakter except >}* {check for class}
    )
    {any charakter except >}*
>
```

*means 0 or multiple times